# Improperly deleted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answer, undelete-answer

RE [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1281311/68374)

User wants to find a "way to get around this 10-lookups-only limit"

The 10 lookup limit is a limit for DNS lookups. Flattening the SPF record to include less DNS lookups and substituting them for IPs (flattening) DOES get around the limit.

The answer is suitable. Maybe @DavidPostill needs to take a look at the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#page-17)?

Question in focus is [SPF Records causing too many DNS lookups](https://superuser.com/q/628810/4377)

Comment: I've undeleted your answer.

Comment: SPF Guru's answer suggests flattening, but explains how it is a solution to what was asked, since it's a workaround.  Your answer, as written, doesn't explain why it's a solution and appears a bit spammy (recommends a "tangential" service without explaining how it solves the problem).  It's been undeleted, but could still attract downvotes because of this.  Just a serving suggestion: it would be a much better answer if you add the explanation and citations you put here.

Comment: thanks, improved answer.